# How could I explore the files when using netrw to edit remote files

Tags: netrw

I can use `:Explore` to go through the current directory and open new files when I use vim locally. But when I use netrw to edit remote files, I cannot do it. For example, I opened a remote file with `vim sftp://name@url//path/to/file.txt`. I opened a file for me. But when I run `:Explore`, I find no tree-like folder structures showed to me. How could I go through the remote files like I did when I edit my local files ?

Answer (score 1):

From [netrw.vim : Network oriented reading, writing, and browsing](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075)

```
REMOTE DIRECTORY BROWSING
    :e [protocol]://[user]@hostname/path/
    :Nread [protocol]://[user]@hostname/path/
```

Note that these commands use directory paths only. (In your example you include a file.)